# How to add div between two classes

Tags: jquery

i have something like this:

```
<div class="ab1">text1</div>
<div class="ab2">text2</div>
```

I want to add div before ab1 and end it after ab2. In final i want this:

```
<div class="ct">
<div class="ab1">text1</div>
<div class="ab2">text2</div>
</div>
```

Insertbefore and instertafter doesnt work. Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) and [wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)

```
$('.ab1, .ab2').wrapAll('<div class="ct" />')
```

Answer (score 1):

use the  [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) function in jquery, this will solve your problem.

like this

```
$(".ab1, .ab2").wrapAll("<div class='ct' />");
```